# Tag system for multiple Item types and groups Schema

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema

I have a groups table and users table, and a many to many relationship between them.

In my app, there are different modules, like question, product,suggestion , etc.

Users can create products/questions/suggestions for a group. Each of the mentioned items belong to a group.

I want to implement a tagging system for these modules. A tag is created by a user, and is specific to only that group. (if group A creates a tag called 'disco', group B should not be able to search for it)

All of the above modules can have the same tag (I would also like to show all the modules when you search for a given tag)

How can I implement this ?

Comment: Can modules have multiple tags?

Comment: yes they can. One module can have multiple tags. One tag can have multiple modules

Comment: ok, and would each tag belong to a user or to a group?

Comment: and are the modules stored all in one table, or are they in many tables

Comment: Multiple modules are in different tables

Comment: Each tag belongs to a group